# How could we initialize Cypress intercepts, in beforeEach properly?

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, cypress

I am relatively new to Cypress and even though it looks straightforward, there some things that I still don't understand. The particular problem:

```
  const componentsRouteMatcher = {
    pathname: '/component-management/api/components',
    query: {
      size: '5',
      page: '0',
      property: 'name',
      direction: 'asc',
      activated: 'true',
      organisationId: '33'
    }
  };

    beforeEach(() => {
   

    cy.interceptStaticDataCalls(); // just a custom command, containing interceptors registrations

    cy.intercept(componentsRouteMatcher, {fixture: 'components/first-5.json'}).as('first5');

    const composSecond5Route = Object.assign({}, componentsRouteMatcher, {query: {page: '1'}});
    cy.intercept(composSecond5Route, {fixture: 'components/second-5.json'}).as('second5');

    const composFirst50Route = Object.assign({}, componentsRouteMatcher, {query: {size: '50'}});
    cy.intercept(composFirst50Route, {fixture: 'components/first-50.json'}).as('first50');

    const composFirst20Route = Object.assign({}, componentsRouteMatcher, {query: {size: '20'}});
    cy.intercept(composFirst20Route, {fixture: 'components/first-20.json'}).as('first20');


    cy.intercept('/component-management/api/functional-areas', {fixture: 'functional-areas/functional-areas.json'}).as('fa');

  });

 it('should display all components based on a default filter', () => {
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.wait(['@first20', '@fa'], {timeout: 5000});
});
```

So the problem is in the last interceptor - it loads a fixture (a JSON file that is a few MB big) but it never intercepts. The contradictive part is that it's listed in the list of available routes by Cypress.
When I move the particular interceptor, at the beginning of beforeEach, it works. I guess there's some async process happening underneath but is not intuitive at all.
Is there any controlled way to setup all those interceptors, without guessing which one to be placed when?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:

```
// standard set of initializations that will be required for all tests
Cypress.Commands.add('interceptStaticDataCalls', () => {
  cy.intercept('/component-management/api/jira/project', { fixture: 'projects.json'});
  cy.intercept('/component-management/api/appclientrelationships/apps', { fixture: 'apps.json'});
  cy.intercept('/component-management/api/appclientrelationships/clients', { fixture: 'clients.json'});
  cy.intercept('/component-management/api/appclientrelationships', { fixture: 'appClientRelationships.json'});
  cy.intercept('/component-management/api/usergroups', { fixture: 'usergroups.json'});
  cy.intercept('/component-management/api/organisations', { fixture: 'organisations.json'});
  cy.intercept('/component-management/api/configs', { fixture: 'configs.json'});
  //we must use pathname here, otherwise it would intercept also the current user request
  cy.intercept({pathname: '/component-management/api/users'}, { fixture: 'users.json'});
})
```

Comment: `cy.intercept()` uses partial matching which is why when you move it to the top it works. My guess is one of the other intercepts is catching `functional-areas`. Do you have `component-management/api` or `component-management`? Posting `componentsRouteMatcher` would be useful.

Comment: Hi @Steve ...i faced already a problem with the partial matcher, so i made sure to use 'pathname' instead, wherever there is a potential risk. This is not the case with this one though. There are no interceptors covering part of the context path `functional-areas` :/

Comment: ***When I move the particular interceptor, at the beginning of beforeEach, it works*** - that contradicts what you just said. You will need to post `componentsRouteMatcher` otherwise it is impossible to guess what is going on.

Comment: @SteveZodiac, sorry, forgot to add the command. Now I did it and as you can see, there aren't any URL conflicts.

Comment: I've noticed that the problem comes with bigger fixture JSON files only. I haven't dig into CYpress code yet, but I could bet that there is an async process loading JSON fixtures and a concurrency problem when  adding an intercept entry.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fit with the change of position making it work.  `interceptStaticDataCalls` is only part of the picture, what is `componentsRouteMatcher`?

Comment: @SteveZodiac, I've just updated it, thx

Comment: So from what I see  - almost everything is async in Cypress ... https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/33477db2a56f65fe9c9e0472f617a6f393b00f25/packages/net-stubbing/lib/server/driver-events.ts#L81   ... which confirms my theory that a bigger fixture would take longer to register a new intercept.

Comment: Not convinced on the size theory. There must be an upper limit on what size fixture is possible, but a few mb should be ok unless the machine memory is low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some reading of Cypress sources, I realized that indeed, almost everything in Cypress is async, as well as the requests interceptors registration (event driven).
To make sure I "visit" the home page, after having all interceptors registered, I just extracted everything into an async function (of course annotated all async processes with await) and then I visit the "/". See the working example bellow:

```
async function initTests() {

  cy.interceptStaticDataCalls();

  await cy.intercept(componentsRouteMatcher, {fixture: 'components/first-5.json'}).as('first5');

  const composSecond5Route = Object.assign({}, componentsRouteMatcher, {query: {page: '1'}});
  await cy.intercept(composSecond5Route, {fixture: 'components/second-5.json'}).as('second5');

  const composFirst50Route = Object.assign({}, componentsRouteMatcher, {query: {size: '50'}});
  await cy.intercept(composFirst50Route, {fixture: 'components/first-50.json'}).as('first50');

  const composFirst20Route = Object.assign({}, componentsRouteMatcher, {query: {size: '20'}});
  await cy.intercept(composFirst20Route, {fixture: 'components/first-20.json'}).as('first20');

  await cy.intercept('/component-management/api/functional-areas', {fixture: 'functional-areas/functional-areas.json'}).as('fa');
}


.....

  beforeEach( () => {
    initTests().then( () => {
      console.log('Initialized!');
      cy.visit("/");
    })
  });
```

Comment: You now have `cy.kcFakeLogin(testUsername)` which was not in your original code. Probably should be after the intercepts, but your question is really obscure.

Comment: Indeed,  I've added later on, since I saw that the rest of the interceptors work ... but I will remove it from the example here, since it wasn't  the main problem